# Creating a function from string which inherits the parent scope

Tags: javascript, function, scope

In Javascript, is there a way to create a function from a string (such as through the new Function() constructor) and have it inherit the parent scope? For example:

```
(function(){
    function yay(){
    }
    var blah = "super yay"
    yay.prototype.testy = new Function("alert(blah)")
    yay.prototype.hello = function(){alert(blah)}
    whee = new yay();
    whee.hello()
    whee.testy()
})()
```

Is there any way to make whee.testy() also alert "super yay"?

Comment: Is there some reason this was downvoted?

Comment: I don't think this is possible.

Comment: I think you shouldn't want to do this. Really, this could be very dangerous. What is the purpose of creating a function from a string? What are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
(function(){
    function yay(){
    }
    var blah = "super yay"
    yay.prototype.testy = eval("(function(){alert(blah)})")//new Function("alert(blah)")
    yay.prototype.hello = function(){alert(blah)}
    whee = new yay();
    whee.hello()
    whee.testy()
})()
```

This seems to work for me, and none of the eval'd data is from any untrusted source. It's just to be used for minifying code.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, combining `function` and `eval` should do what you want:

```
// blah exists inside the 'hello' function
yay.prototype.hello = function(){ alert(blah) }
// blah also exists inside the 'testy' function, and
// is therefore accessible to eval().
yay.prototype.testy = function(){ eval('alert(blah)') }
```

Comment: But the OP must be **very** sure that the string doesn't contain any malicious code. I'm interested in the way the string is assigned its value.

Comment: Yes, yes... eval is evil and all that. Judging by the way OP created the anonymous function around his code, it's not his first day doing JS.

Comment: I'm just using eval/Function to better compress some code, it's not stuff which is user-inputted, but I just have some code where there are lots of functions with very little code inside, function(e){var t=this;return e(t)?[t]:[]} and there's a substantial amount of bytes being used up with the function(e){var t=this;return}.

Comment: LOL... +1 to your comment - I like the way you responded to the typical "eval is evil" advice

Answer (score 1):

This should give you what you want...

```
var inputAction = "alert(blah)";
yay.prototype.testy = eval("(function(){ " + inputAction + "; })")
```

It basically wraps your intended action inside an anonymous function, this gets fully evaluated on the eval, but isn't run right away, it's wrapped into a function.

You can go a little farther here, but without knowing what you want to accomplish it's hard to say.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why `whee.testy` doesn't work is because declaring a function using `new Function("alert(blah)")` creates the function outside the current closure. Since `blah` is defined inside your closure, you do not have access to it, and it throws an undefined error.

Here is a proof of concept example:

```
var blah = "global (window) scope";

(function(){
    function yay(){
    }
    var blah = "closure scope";

    yay.prototype.testy = new Function("alert(blah)");
    yay.prototype.hello = function(){ alert(blah); }
    whee = new yay();
    whee.hello();
    whee.testy();
})();
```

Comment: I know why it won't work, but is there a way to make it work?

Comment: @antimatter15: No... `new Function(string)` defines a function in the global scope. This is by design. Use anonymous functions instead.

Answer (score -1):

You mean eval?

```
(function(){
    function yay(){
    }
    var blah = "super yay"
    yay.prototype.testy = new Function(eval("alert(blah)")) // <---------------
    yay.prototype.hello = function(){alert(blah)}
    whee = new yay();
    whee.hello()
    whee.testy()
})()
```

However there are two morally objectionable feature of JS here.
1) eval is "evil", and
2) the code inside the eval can see the variables outside.

Comment: `eval` is **evil**! Don't use it! Don't!

Comment: And here's a better explanation why not to use eval: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/197769/when-is-javascripts-eval-not-evil/198031#198031

Comment: Like I said: morally objectionable

Comment: new Function(str) and eval(str) are practically identical. The way OP uses new Function() is correct - you don't need eval there.

Comment: Here, I don't think doing new Function(eval("alert(blah)") works. There, alert(blah) is being executed immediately rather than when the function is called.

Function and eval aren't exactly identical, and here is a case where it's different. Functions don't get access to the local variables of the scope they were created in, while eval does.

Comment: @antimatter15
You are correct.  Function(eval("alert(blah)") is executed immediately.
 
 
eval("(Function(...))"); ... very tricky

Answer (score -1):

You don't need eval.

You have to concatenate the blah to the string function but JavaScript will complain that there is no ";" just before the concatenation this is because blah is just some text when you concatenate it. You have to escape two "\"" around the variable blah in order to make it look like a string with text in it.

```
(function(){
    function yay(){
    }
 var blah = "super yay"

 yay.prototype.testy = new Function("alert(\""+blah+"\")")
 yay.prototype.hello = function(){alert(blah)}
 whee = new yay();
 whee.hello()
 whee.testy()
})()
```

This will alert "super yay" two times!

Comment: But if I updated the value for "blah", then whee.testy() would alert the wrong value.